# Django The 'picture' attribute has no file associated with it. При попытке сжать изображение при помощи PIL

Tags: python, django, изображения, django-model, pillow

При попытке сжать изображение после отправки формы появляется ошибка в строке  12.    im = Image.open(image) в файле models.py

Само содержание ошибки:

```
ValueError at /addpost/
The 'picture' attribute has no file associated with it.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/addpost/
Django Version: 4.2.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The 'picture' attribute has no file associated with it.
Exception Location: E:\Programming\WEB\django1\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py, line 41, in _require_file
Raised during:  cityconnection.views.AddPost
Python Executable:  E:\Programming\WEB\django1\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.10
Python Path:    
['E:\\Programming\\WEB\\django1\\testsite',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python310',
 'E:\\Programming\\WEB\\django1\\venv',
 'E:\\Programming\\WEB\\django1\\venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 18 Aug 2023 09:25:23 +0000
```

Что только не делал, переделывал по другим примерам - ошибка выводилась аналогичная. В чем может быть дело?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from pytils.translit import slugify
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files import File


def compress(image):
    im = Image.open(image)
    # create a BytesIO object
    im_io = BytesIO()
    # save image to BytesIO object
    im.save(im_io, 'JPEG', quality=70)
    # create a django-friendly Files object
    new_image = File(im_io, name=image.name)
    return new_image


# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    creator_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Автор')  # id автора
    city = models.CharField(max_length=63, default='Н', verbose_name='Город')  # Город
    title = models.CharField(max_length=127, verbose_name='Заголовок')  # Заголовок
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True, verbose_name='URL')
    content = models.TextField()  # Текстовое содержание
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d", verbose_name='Изображение', blank=True, null=True)  # Изображение
    tags = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=255, verbose_name='Теги', null=True)  # Теги
    category = models.ForeignKey('PostCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Категория')  # Категория поста
    coordinate_x = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='Коорд. метки X')  # Координаты Х
    coordinate_y = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='Коорд. метки Y')  # Координаты У
    time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Создан')  # Время создания
    time_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Изменен')  # Время редактирования
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Статус публикации')  # Статус публикации

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('posts', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        new_image = compress(self.picture)
        # set self.image to new_image
        self.image = new_image
        # save
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты сообщества'
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        ordering = ['-time_create']  # Сортировка
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = []

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import *


class AddPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'].empty_label = "Категория не выбрана"

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields =  ['city',
                   'title',
                   'content',
                   'picture',
                   'tags',
                   'category',
                   'coordinate_x',
                   'coordinate_y']
```

**add_post_page.html**

```
{% extends 'cityconnection/base.html' %}
{% load cityconnection_tags %}

{% block content%}
<h1>Создание поста</h1>
<hr>
<form action="{% url 'add_post' %}" method="post" style="float: left;">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <div class="">{{ form.non_field_errors }}</div>
    <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Покажите где и как вы используете форму, а также покажите html-код этой формы

Comment: Добавил html-код в вопрос. Пока что просто обычная страница с формой, которая автоматически подтягивается от модели. Пользователь заполняет обязательные поля и отправляет post запрос на сервер. В дополнение можно прикрепить изображение, которое будет выводиться на странице поста.  Если не добавлять сжатие в классе модели, то всё работает как часы: изображение загружается, пост отображается нормально.

Comment: Как минимум сразу видно, что в форме вы не указали `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, а значит она не способна отправлять файлы

Comment: ...и на этом фоне заявление «изображение загружается» выглядит крайне странно, потому что оно в принципе не должно загружаться

Comment: Сейчас добавил enctype и теперь компрессия заработала как надо. (тем не менее, без неё и отсутствующем enctype  Django все равно как-то умудрялся производить сохранение). Можете добавить свой ответ, чтобы я мог выбрать его как лучший?

Comment: Меня ещё смущает строчка `self.image = new_image` потому что в модели Post не существует поля image

Comment: Я переписал уже. Там проблема была в том, что даже до той ошибка не давала дойти.